# JT400.jar Disable Login Screen

Tags: jdbc, jt400

Can anyone help me out? I have small utility application that uses the Jt400-6.7.jar to connect to an AS400 server.

Please see the following code

```
private Connection buildConnection(String url, String userName, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;

        Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");

        DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(10000);

        //OVER HERE!!! 
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

        return connection;
    }
```

The code above works but if the the username or the password is wrong the application creates the following login screen. It happens when  DriverManager.getConnection() is executed.

Cant post a picture but it looks something like this

```
Signon to the system           X

System:         AS400Server
User ID:        User ID
Password:       ********

       O Default User ID
       O Save Password

    OK            Cancel
```

Can anyone tell me how to disable this feature??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way to disable this feature is to set the JVM property,  com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.guiAvailable=false.

From a java command line, you would set this using java  -Dcom.ibm.as400.access.AS400.guiAvailable=false ...

Here is an example using the jdbc client included in jt400.jar

```
C:\>java -cp jt400.jar -Dcom.ibm.as400.access.AS400.guiAvailable=false com.ibm.as400.access.jdbcClient.Main jdbc:as400:/SYSTEM
Warning:  Unable to connect to jdbc:as400:/SYSTEM using null
CON is not defined
```

The second way to disable this feature is to use the prompt=false connection property.  For example.

```
C:\jtopen_build\dist6>java -cp jt400.jar com.ibm.as400.access.jdbcClient.Main jdbc:as400:/SYSTEM;prompt=false
Warning:  Unable to connect to jdbc:as400:/SYSTEM;prompt=false using null
CON is not defined
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply was a weekend on my end. Anyway I am calling the driver with my sample code above. I there anyway for me to pass these parameters using my code above. Sorry for my ignorance...

Comment: Just add the line ... url += ";prompt=false"; ... before ... connection = DriverManager.getConnection

Answer (score 1):

Another method for preventing the GUI password prompt.

```
AS400.setPasswordExpirationWarningDays(-1);
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("extended metadata", "true");
properties.put("user", userProfile);
properties.put("password", password);
properties.put("driver", "native");
properties.put("prompt", "false");
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver());
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:as400://somedomain.com", properties);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, when calling a RPG program from java, same Sign-on pop up arrives.You can turn it off by setting com.ibm.as400.access.AS400 object's setGuiAvailable(false);

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it when defining the DataSource:

```
final AS400JDBCDataSource dataSourceISeries = new AS400JDBCDataSource();
dataSourceISeries.setDatabaseName(...);
dataSourceISeries.setUser(...);
...
dataSourceISeries.setPrompt(false);
```